# Event bound with jQuery's on method fires only once

Tags: jquery, events

well, I know the title might sound miss leading but bear with me...

I have the following code that I use with the intention of reuse a couple of nodes to construct a simple yes/no dialog:

```
var myDialog = function(e) {
    if(myDialog.dialog === undefined){
        var container = $('<div><h2>Are you sure you want to delete this Item?</h2></div>'),
            yesBtn = $('<input type="button" value="Yes" id="yesBtn"/>').appendTo(div),
            noBtn =  $('<input type="button" value="No" id="noBtn"/>').appendTo(div);

       myDialog.dialog = container; 
       $('#yesBtn').on({ click: function(e) { console.log('Yes'); } } );
       $('#noBtn').live('click', function(e) { console.log('No'); });
    }

    //I am using a third party lib called facebox to create the showbox
    $.facebox(myDialog.dialog);
};
```

Then this function is used by an button that, when clicked, displays the dialog box (correctly every time) and, when clicked the first time, the yes/no buttons fires correctly, but when the dialog is shown again, none of the two events fires.

This problem gets fixed if I use ***live*** insted of ***on*** but I have been reading that the good practice is to start using the latter instead of the former.

Any comments will be of great help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably u are not using 1.7 jquery (i.e using old version). Just to rule out the possibility

Comment: Sorry I didn't point it out at the beginning, but I am using jQuery 1.7 ;)

Answer (score 0):

i dont think it works when you send an options hash to on()

instead of

```
$('#yesBtn').on({ click: function(e) { console.log('Yes'); } } );
```

try

```
$('#yesBtn').on("click", function(e) { console.log('Yes'); }  );
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the jQuery version you are using. Check what your jQuery version is. As of jQuery 1.7 you should use `on` use live is deprecated. You cant use `on` if you are using 1.4.

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

And you are also using `on` the wrong way.

1. You passed in the wrong parameters.
2. You can only pass in object on the third parameter on `on`. You pass it in as object data.
3. Using on means that you put a listener and then wait until that event bubbles up to that listener from the DOM element you select, thus, this is the right way doing it:

   $(document).on("click", "#yesBtn", function(e) { console.log("Yes"); }  );

In that case it bubbles to `document`. you may want to make it so that the event gets bubbled up to only the container of `#yesBtn`. you can Wrap `#yesBtn` inside a div or something